# Invoking method on null reference kotlin extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

So, I'm getting a really weird error in my fragment:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.halalrishtey.ProfessionalDetailsFragment.onViewCreated(ProfessionalDetailsFragment.kt:47)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:892)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManagerImpl.java:2100)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1874)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1830)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1727)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl$2.run(FragmentManagerImpl.java:150)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

I'm getting null reference on a button which I access inside `onViewCreated` function through `kotlin-extensions` like so:

```
uploadAdhar_Button.setOnClickListener {
    findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_professionalDetails_to_uploadImageFragment)
}
```

It was working before, I don't know what went wrong please help!

Comment: Probably `uploadAdhar_Button` is not associated with your current fragment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `import` statements of `ProfessionalDetailsFragment` and `import` the **correct synthetic**. It should be the same xml which is inflated by `ProfessionalDetailsFragment`.

My best guess is that `uploadAdhar_Button` `id` is used by some other views in another `.xml file` too !

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_professional_details.*
```

Also **delete** the other `import statement` of the unused `.xml`